# gcp pubsub to bigquery subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to publish some data ( in avro schema with JSON encoding) to gcp pubsub and i have enable bigquery subscription so that data will auto route to BQ table.

Avro Schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Sample",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

BigQuery Table:

```
Sample_Table(abc: Integer marked as NULLABLE)
```

When below data is published to topic, then no data is written to BigQuery Table

```
{
  "abc": {
    "string": "testdata"
  }
}
```

However, when i publish null values to topic as below, then null is inserted into BigQuery table.

```
{
  "abc": null
}
```

Seems like BigQuery subscription is not recognizing the json structure internally?

Can someone please point me to something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Avro schemas that have a nullable type where the messages are encoded via JSON. You can track the progress on the fix in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242757468).